# CSS border-radius on really small objects in Chrome Canary

Tags: css, google-chrome

How does one achieve CSS border-radius on really small objects in Chrome Canary?

This 3px high line with a 2px border radius zoomed in at 600% reveals that not much is going on:

[image]

Works fine in the regular Google Chrome, Firefox etc.

```css
div {
  height: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I can see it on FF if I zoom in http://jsfiddle.net/43ax8qL0/ you can even see it on your example on this page after zooming in

Comment: In what webbrowser and what operating system do you notice this behaviour?

Comment: True that. I was using Chrome Canary (updated my question).

Comment: you can see the 1px getting rounded on each corner

Comment: Must be a bug in Canary.

Comment: *Still* a bug in Chrome Canary

Answer (score 3):

At 3px, only 1 pixel can be chopped from each corner to create any effect. A 400% zoom in Chrome shows rounded corners:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I think it's a bug in Canary.